# Why the gray line is drawn between two non-identical keyframes?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I thought **the horizontal bar** in the ***Action Editor/Dope Sheet*** **is drawn when two keyframes are identical**. In my case I have keyframes with different values, but the horizontal line is still drawn.

In the pictures below you can see that rotation values are different, but the horizontal bar is still drawn between keyframes:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't have the same thickness that the classical grey line though

Comment: Maybe it's because of the theme that I'm using. I'm suing "default++" theme, maybe it affects the thickness?

Comment: I mean look at its thickness after frame 13, it changes, same thing between frame 1 and 4, not the same thickness than between 6 and 13, so what does it mean?  :/

Comment: I have no idea :/

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact you've keyframed everything about the bone and say the transform and scale is still the same but the rotations are different. Other than that, I'm not sure. Perhaps try removing all key frames and just keying rotation values? If that's what you did anyway, then I'm at a loss...

Comment: Even though the scale and location are still the same,since rotations are different  there shouldn't be any gray lines in the rotation channel. Am I wrong?